# SQL Incremenet and Reset Variable Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, count

I have probably missed something simple with my problem. However its like me to overlook any small details. But I have been searching for a while now and havent come across anything similar to my issue.

Setup:
SQL 2005, Stored Procedure.

I have a table that is updated frequently with call attempts. Using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to tie all the records together i.e.

```
xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx | 20/06/2011 12:00 | 10
```

I want to have a stored procedure that Grabs all the records, and sorts them by the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and at the same time, producing a counter for the attempts. i.e.

```
1111-1111-1111-1111    | 20/06/2011 12:05    |  10 | 0    
1111-1111-1111-1111    | 20/06/2011 12:06    |  30 | 1   
2222-2222-2222-2222    | 20/06/2011 12:10    | 120 | 0  
3333-3333-3333-3333    | 20/06/2011 12:20    |  50 | 0
```

From the above it should be simple to be able to to indentify the call attempts and add on the number. However im probably being very silly.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Chris

Comment: Do you need to calculate the values of the last column during the INSERT, retrospectively for a legacy table, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

e.g.

```
SELECT ID, DateField, FieldA, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateField ASC) AS Counter
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ID, DateField
```

The PARTITION BY basically resets the counter for each distinct ID and the following ORDER BY ensures the counter is assigned incrementally ordered by the Date field. Note this will be a counter starting from 1 each time. If you want it to start from 0, you can just subtract 1 in the SELECT

Comment: Thank you very much, the PARTITION BY was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the "group by" clause *(with a count)* in SQL ?

You could use "order by" to perform the sort *(although its not immediately apparent how SQL implements that or what use it would be)*.

Also, the question title doesn't seem to match what you're asking.